# How to launch .jar file from C++ WITHOUT console window

Tags: c++, jar

When I launch .jar file like:

```
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    system("start javaw -splash:someImage.png -jar someFile.jar");

    return 0;
}
```

Also I have defined -mwindows option in g++ compiler.

Before splash screen - a black console shows for a few millisecods. Is there any solution to avoid that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx

There's a flag [CREATE_NO_WINDOW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), pass Your command as parameters.

Comment: unfortunetley i need to go to work, i'll try to make one in the evening :)

Comment: midht be at some use: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4ee7b572-1306-4487-adb6-39ee23652e23/createnowindow-flag-used-in-createprocess-function-does-not-work-in-windows-server-2008-r2?forum=winserver2008appcompatabilityandcertification

Answer (score 3):

In your case the `system()` function just executes the `cmd.exe` with `start ...` arguments. So the black console window belongs to the started `cmd` process. The `javaw` program has no console window. And it will be enough to create a new process with `javaw -splash:someImage.png -jar someFile.jar` command line as described on the [Creating Processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page.

Answer (score 2):

My current working example based on Ernestas Gruodis and others, with no warning

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{   
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    char cmdline[] = " -jar some.jar";
    // Start the child process. 
    if( !CreateProcess( "javaw.exe",   // No module name (use command line)
        cmdline,        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        CREATE_NO_WINDOW,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi)            // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return 1;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with MinGW

```
g++ test.cpp -o test.exe -Wl,--subsystem,windows
```

`-Wl,--subsystem,windows` means no console window.

Answer (score 1):

My preliminary solution now is:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    STARTUPINFO si;
    memset(&si, 0, sizeof (STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof (STARTUPINFO);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    si.wShowWindow = FALSE;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    memset(&pi, 0, sizeof (PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    // Start the child process.

    if (!CreateProcess("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\javaw.exe",
            " -jar install.jar", // Command line.
            NULL, // Process handle not inheritable.
            NULL, // Thread handle not inheritable.
            0, // Set handle inheritance to FALSE.
            CREATE_NO_WINDOW, // ON VISTA/WIN7, THIS CREATES NO WINDOW
            NULL, // Use parent's environment block.
            NULL, // Use parent's starting directory.
            &si, // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure.
            &pi)) // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure.
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    return 0;
}
```

But I get the warning:

> main.cpp: In function 'int WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)':
>   main.cpp:38:16: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to
>   'LPSTR {aka char*}' [-Wwrite-strings]
>                &pi)) // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure.

How it is possible to do it proper way without warnings?

PS - if someone wants to **add an icon to exe file** - [here](http://forums.netbeans.org/download.php?id=985) is superb instructions how to do that in NetBeans IDE. Just put in resource.rc these lines:

```
#include "ids.h"  
IDI_ICON ICON "nice.ico"
```

and in ids.h file:

```
#define IDI_ICON  101
```

That's all.

Comment: Add `TCHAR args[] = _T("-jar install.jar");` and pass it as the second argument of the `CreateProcess` function.