# I am unable to run executable jar from c++ program

Tags: java, c++

I used Eclipse to create a runable jar file. The java program writes a number to a .txt file. When I manually click on the file the program runs and creates the .txt as it should. However, when I try to run the .jar from my c++ code, it seems to run but no txt file is created. I tried this method in c++

```
system("C:\Users\anon\Downloads\KidCod\KidCod\Java\WeatherFinder02.jar");
```

However, it didn't work. So I tried this method:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "C:\Users\anon\Downloads\KidCod\KidCod\Java\WeatherFinder02.jar.c", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

But it still doesn't work. I don't get any errors or anything like that. I tried to run it in c# as well but it didn't work. Why won't my txt file successfully be created?

Comment: Try running "java -jar yourjar.jar" from the command line first. And then simply use that command. A JAR always needs a JVM to be run "on".

Answer (score 1):

I think if you have to open a file through system you need `start` because that is what you use to start a file in cmd so

`system("start C:\Users\anon\Downloads\KidCod\KidCod\Java\WeatherFinder02.jar");`

You could also try to compile the jar file to exe

Comment: You cant `start` jar files, won't work. You need to call `java -jar somename.jar`

Comment: @Trapster DK I already tried that and it didn't work. I wanted to convert the jar to exe but it looks to confusing. I'm still somewhat new to programming btw.

Comment: @Amongalen I tried system("java -jar C:\\Users\\anon\\Downloads\\KidCod\\KidCod\\Java\\WeatherFinder02.jar");  and it didn't work

Comment: the java program just writes a number to a txt file? can't you just do that in c++?

Comment: @Samurai did you try calling that from the command line / terminal first? I don't really know C++ so don't know how it should be done there. However, you use that command to start jars from command line.

Comment: @Trapster DK The end result in the weather temperature is written to a file. The java program goes to a weather website and scrapes the data from it. With C++ I can't really do that. That is why I need to start the jar file from c++

Comment: @Amongalen OK. I entered this into the command line: "java -jar C:\\Users\\anon\\Downloads\\KidCod\\KidCod\\Java\\WeatherFinder02.jar and it worked. Which is good. However, how will I get my c++ program to run it?

Comment: please try with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552881/how-to-launch-jar-file-from-c-without-console-window

Comment: @RohitHajare I already looked over that. And i'm not really familiar with that. It's confusing to be frank.

Comment: @Samurai how is it working maybe i could recreate it in c++
Is it taking the HTML and just taking a specific line it wouldn't be that hard to replicate

Comment: @TrapsterDK Here is my code its pretty short: https://justpaste.it/2366w

Comment: @samurai are the one running the program using windows?

Comment: @TrapsterDK I am using windows 10. If you mean console windows, yes it is using a console window. But that is only for testing purposes.

Comment: I'll send you a message wen it's done. IT Will be done in 24 hours have to sleep soon

Comment: I am having a hardcore time splitting It Will use some more time tomorrow

Comment: @Samurai this code should do what you wanted it to https://justpaste.it/3jroq sorry that it took so long

Comment: @TrapsterDK Thanks! No worries on the wait, this is just a side project i'm working on. I don't have much time to look over it atm.However, when I built it there was an error. Maybe it something silly i'm forgetting to do.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check your java.exe in the PATH variable.

If you don't have one, you should add your java to it.

Here is my env on the msys2 and MinGW32.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/D/DEV/SDK/JDK/jdk1.8.0_152
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Second, see if your java is working with -version option as following

```
java -version

java version "1.8.0_152-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-ea-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.152-b02, mixed mode)
```

Then use the command in the source code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    system("java -version");

    return 0;
}
```

The output should be the same with that of command line before.

To solve your problem, i create two files, one is a simple java file called WriteFileExample.java and the other is one manifest file.

> WriteFileExample.java

```
package com.tobee.test;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class WriteFileExample {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrintWriter out = null;

        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("aa.txt")));
            out.print(1);
            out.print(3);
            out.print(4);
            out.print(7);
            out.print(9);
            out.println();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if(out != null)
            {
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

> manifest : MANIFEST.MF

```
Main-Class: com.tobee.WriteFileExample
```

I compile it and make it jar with the manifest file by,

```
javac -d . WriteFileExample.java
jar -cvmf MANIFEST.MF WeatherFinder02.jar com/tobee/test/WriteFileExample.class
```

Finaaly, you have a executable jar file now.
It should be working without any erros by following command, 
java -jar WeatherFinder02.jar

You will have an aa.txt file in that directory.

Then, It is time to append the command line to the c source code.

```
int main()
{
    system("java -version");
    system("java -jar WeatherFinder02.jar");

    return 0;
}
```

I have no problem so far.

I hope this one help.